# Bitbucket Maximum repo size with git-LFS

Tags: git, bitbucket, git-lfs

I have a repository on bitbucket and I plan pushing some big files ( ~5gb ) on it. The files are marked as lfs with git-lfs but I cannot stop wonder if there are limitations even with that. So after reading [this](https://confluence.atlassian.com/bitbucket/what-kind-of-limits-do-you-have-on-repository-file-size-273877699.html) I still cannot understand If I will hit a limit or not.

Also is the limit only applied on the repository? So if I have 10 repositories of 1gb each under 1 project of 1 organization it will not be a problem correct?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On Free plan it's 1GB for Git LFS for **all your repository**, it's **per account**. Like also "Build minutes" for CI/CD.

See [Bitbucket pricing](https://bitbucket.org/product/pricing)

Comment: Literally never thought to check pricing.! thank you